# Rails 5.0.0.1: can not create a class instance from the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following a video tutorial made in June 2012. The Ruby version 1.9.3, and Rails version is 3 at that time. Now I am trying out the code examples in Rails 5.0.0.1.

We know that nowadays `strong parameters` must be used in a `create` action. Is that also applicable when using the console to create an instance object of a class?

In the exercise a model User was generated by `rails g scaffold user name movie`. The next instruction was to `rake db:migrate`(of course), and then go into the console and create a User record. All went well; record created and saved with all fields having a value.

But now comes the part where my question is about: the next command was:

`rails g scaffold car user:belongs_to condition year:integer`.

OK; `rake db:migrate` again, and open the console. This happened when I wanted to create a Car record:

```
>> car = Car.create(year: 2003, condition: 'ok')
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<Car id: nil, user_id: nil, condition: "ok", year: 2003, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

No record was created! I suspect it has to do with the `strong parameters` in Rails 4 and 5?

At last, here are my questions:

- What went wrong? And is there an alternative way, using the console to create?
- Is this because of the relation of the Car model: `belongs_to :user`?
- I know there are gems that 'mimic' a state before the introduction of strong parameters, but I'd rather not use these; it feels like cheating!

Comment: You didn't specify a user for the car. Inspect `car.errors` and you'll see why it wasn't saved.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: you are right! I provided an ```id``` and a ```user_id```, and now I _can_ create a new record! Thank you! I thought that the ```id``` would automagically be generated, but obviously in this case not!

Comment: Moreover: I can not create with a ```user_id``` of a non-existing user! Rails has a lot of hidden __gems__ in store for me!

Comment: yeah, it's called "referential integrity" :)

Comment: Yes, Sergio, I am learning new tricks; and for everyone interested, I found this article, that looks like a good explanation:
> https://richonrails.com/articles/foreign-keys-in-rails-4-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 5 requires `belongs_to` associations by default since [this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937/files).

You can specify that the field is optional by using `belongs_to :user, optional: true`.

Also, if your model fails to save, it's often helpful to take a look at its `errors` object.

You can do this by doing something like `puts car.errors`.

Strong parameters won't affect anything you do in the console. The whole point of them was to move mass-assignment protection out of models and into controllers.

Comment: Funny: I can create a record by only giving in an existing ```user_id```, leaving out all other parameters! Because there are no ```validates``` defined in the classes?
The tutorial (remember, from 2012) shows that the user_id was ```nil```, but with the current Rails version, that is impossible...

Comment: Yep, `user_id` is the only required field since you don't have any other validations on the `Car` model. If you make the `user_id` field optional by doing that `optional: true` bit, then you'd be able to create a new `Car` with no parameters, like: `car = Car.create!`, and `car` would be valid. E.g. `car.is_valid? == true`.

Comment: Look what I did! I can still fool around:

`code`

>> car = Car.first
  Car Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "cars".* FROM "cars" ORDER BY "cars"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Car id: 1, user_id: 1, condition: "ok", year: 2003, created_at: "2016-09-17 17:23:43", updated_at: "2016-09-17 17:23:43">
>> car.update_attribute(:user_id, nil)
`code`

I am sorry; I do not understand how to put code in a comment :-(

All I want to show is that the user_id can be set to nil, again.